# how to ensure CGI env var SSL_SESSION_ID is not blank?

Tags: apache

Is there some `mod_ssl` configuration magic to ensure that the `SSL_SESSION_ID` env var in the CGI script/program environment is never blank? I have multiple Apache servers, all of which are version 2.4.x and when a browser fetches a page on initial connect to them I see a hit and miss result.  On some browsers (latest MS Explorer) the `SSL_SESSION_ID` is not blank. On latest Firefox and Chrome the `SSL_SESSION_ID` is simply blank. Hit reload in the browser and the `SSL_SESSION_ID` is returned as expected and the `SSL_SESSION_RESUMED` changes from "Initial" to "resumed". Yes the "Initial" has an upper case letter "I" for some reason.

This env var is needed for some application space issues.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

apparently the only way is to use the (insecure) SSLv3:

> Solution was found at Red Hat site which states that SSLv3 must be in
>   the SSLProtocol list and the there is no promise to deliver a
>   SSL_SESSION_ID  in the TLS protocol spec.
>
> Therefore change SSLProtocol config to :
>
> ```
> SSLProtocol +SSLv3 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.2
> ```

explanation:

> A generic web browser sends "Client Hello" message with "SessionTicket
>   TLS" extension of data length=0 during TLS handshake. If
>   "SessionTicket TLS"(data length=0) is presented by the client, the
>   server will handle a session ticket instead of a session id.
>   Therefore, the server does not generate a session id. On the second
>   access, it sends "Client Hello" with a session ticket which was
>   received in the first access, and the server validate it and, if it is
>   valid, generates a session id. This behavior is defined by RFC5077 and
>   the reason why a session id does not appear at a first access and
>   appears at a second access. This is an unavoidable limitation as long
>   as TLSv1 is used and the client implementation uses the "SessionTicket
>   TLS" extension, however, when configuring the client to use SSLv3
>   instead of TLSv1, a session id always appears, because SSLv3 has no
>   such extension. Please consider using SSLv3 if possible.

from https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56324